# How to find a user in different collections in Firestore using ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have two collections: `users_unprocessed` and `users_processed`. When a user is new, he will be added to the `users_unprocessed` collection. If he is processed, he will be deleted and added to the `users_processed`.

I want to create a list with all users. Therefore I need to find a user in `users_processed` or `users_unprocessed`. The list should be reactively and show live updates, therefor I need to use `.onSnapshot()`.

```
database.collection("users_unprocessed").doc(id).onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
  if (snapshot.numChildren > 0) {
    setFetchedUser(snapshot.data());
  } else {
    database.collection('users_unprocessed').doc(id).onSnapshot((snap) => {
       if (snapshot.numChildren > 0) { 
          assignUser(snap)
       } else {
          // Error Handling
       }
    })
  }
```

This code is not giving my any result no matter of the doc exists in the `users_unprocessed` or `users_processed`.

Answer (score 0):

If both collections are correctly set you just need to use the forEach function on each of them and put them on an array or list or whatever you want. Something like that:

```js
const allUsers = [];
database.collection("users_unprocessed").onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        allUsers.push(doc.data().name);
    });
});
```

And then you can do the same with the other collection in the same list. If you don't want to put them on an Array but you have any other method or function you just need to change the last part.